# Sort pandas dataframe by two columns using key in one of them, "kind mergesort", not working

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, mergesort, reindex

I am trying to sort a dataframe by 2 consecutive conditions, `col[0]` and `col[2]`, the input data looks like this:

[image]

My desired output looks like this (sorted by `col[0]` and then by `col[2]`):

[image]

The second order is custom [gene,mRNA,five_prime_UTR, CDS, three_prime_UTR], so I used a `categorical` function.

```
df[2] = pd.Categorical(df[2],categories=['gene','mRNA','five_prime_UTR', 'CDS', 'three_prime_UTR'],ordered=True)
```

And then, I have to use `index_natsorted`, to avoid alphabetical order and non-desired outputs in `col[0]`, not desired output example:

[image]

`df.reindex` is working fine, but if I tried to concatenate the first ordering with the second one (`kind='mergesort'`), the order (in `col[0]`) is not saved

```
df = df.reindex(index=order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(df[0], reverse=False))).sort_values(by=[2], ascending=True, kind='mergesort')
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "col1": ["chr5","chr5","chr5","chr3","chr3","chr3","chr3","chr2","chr2","chr2","chr11"],
  "col2": ["CDS","gene","mRNA","three_prime_UTR","gene","CDS","mRNA","CDS","gene","mRNA","CDS"]
}
#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Before Sort:",df)
df['col2'] = pd.Categorical(df['col2'],categories=['gene','mRNA','five_prime_UTR', 'CDS', 'three_prime_UTR'],ordered=True)
df['new'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(\d+$)').astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(by=['new', 'col2']).drop('new', axis=1)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print("\n\nAfter sort:",df)
```

For col2 i have used categorical sort and for col1 retrived number in end and sorted based on it and dropped newly created column "new".

Output:

```
Before Sort:      col1             col2
0    chr5              CDS
1    chr5             gene
2    chr5             mRNA
3    chr3  three_prime_UTR
4    chr3             gene
5    chr3              CDS
6    chr3             mRNA
7    chr2              CDS
8    chr2             gene
9    chr2             mRNA
10  chr11              CDS


After sort:      col1             col2
0    chr2             gene
1    chr2             mRNA
2    chr2              CDS
3    chr3             gene
4    chr3             mRNA
5    chr3              CDS
6    chr3  three_prime_UTR
7    chr5             gene
8    chr5             mRNA
9    chr5              CDS
10  chr11              CDS
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, however the sorting for col[0] is not working as I would like, can you please take a look at the differences between the desired output and the last one I got? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer with input and output. can you verify once

Comment: Many thanks, @Manjari, I did that too. I updated my question, please see the order in col[0], figure 3. I used reindex to get col[0] ordered by number, rather than by string. If I use your code, I will get exactly the same result as in figure 3.

Comment: I also updated the last figure, hopefully, this will clarify the error.

Comment: Another option to see my error in your example is adding chr11, chr22. I am getting chr1,chr11,chr2,chr22, chr3... and so on.

Comment: @Fcallejas Please check the edited answer, it might help you

Comment: it worked! I can't upvote because I'm a new user. But many thanks, Manjari!